Does Entity Framework Core support queries based on a table of custom values?
I'm using a T-SQL query like
SELECT 
    WeekStart,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) 
     FROM Logins 
     WHERE Timestamp >= WeekStart 
       AND Timestamp < DATEADD(wk, 1, WeekStart)) ActiveUsers,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Downloads 
     WHERE Timestamp >= WeekStart 
       AND Timestamp < DATEADD(wk, 1, WeekStart)) Downloads
FROM 
    (SELECT WeekStart 
     FROM 
         (VALUES ('2024-12-09'), ('2024-12-02'), ('2024-11-25'), ('2024-11-18') /* values generated by code, potentially more */) AS Weeks(WeekStart)) Weeks

It returns 2 values for each of the supplied input dates. The date values are dynamic, typically the list contains 20 dates. The result might look like this:



WeekStart
ActiveUsers
Downloads




2024-12-09
123
456


2024-12-02
99
333


...





Is there any chance to convert this into Entity Framework Core code that does not depend on the SQL dialect?

Why do you want to move this into EF Core? Because I theoretically could see how this is made with EF but a Query like this would be a performance drop. Other may be able to come up with a solution to make it even but to my knowledge if performance is the sole purpose it wont be the desired way

Short answer is no, not supported out of the box by EF Core. There was a package called MemoryJoin trying to utilize VALUES syntax, but it seems to be dead.

You can create a calendar table and use that with normal EF joins

Thanks for the clear answer @IvanStoev. I was hoping that I had just not found the right search terms.

@siggemannen - Agreed. I'm aware of the option but was trying to avoid database schema and content changes.

@LMA - The purpose is to be independent of the database's SQL dialect. But I don't want to replace the single database query with one call for each date value or even each data point.

@PaulB. ah yes in this case... no my solution would have made multiple calls

It's possible to compose a raw SQL query with other Queryables, as long as the raw SQL itself is composable.
Using that principle, you can construct an IQueryable that returns a tally table and do all kinds of nice stuff with it, among which creating an on-the-fly composable IQueryable of dates:
using var context = new MyContext();

var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1); // Decide here where to start.
var tally = """
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ao.object_id) - 1 AS Value
            FROM sys.all_objects ao
            """;
var tallyQuery = context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<long>(tally).Take(20);

var result = from d in tallyQuery.Select(l => startDate.AddDays(7 * l))
    select new 
    {
        d,
        ActiveUsers = context.Logins
           .Where(x => x.Timestamp >= d && x.Timestamp < d.AddDays(7))
           .Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count(),
        Downloads = context.Downloads
            .Where(x => x.Timestamp >= d && x.Timestamp < d.AddDays(7))
            .Count()
    };

Of course, the part FROM sys.all_objects ao is database vendor-specific, but it could easily be replaced by any (relatively low-traffic) table in the application's schema that is large enough to supply the required amount of records.

Thanks for the suggestion. I figured out that I can use your approach and create the table like SELECT CAST('2024-12-09' AS DATE) Value UNION SELECT CAST('2024-12-02' AS DATE) UNION SELECT CAST('2024-11-25' AS DATE) .... This should work for SQL-92 databases, I believe.

Sure, that works. But many databases support this ROW_NUMBER() OVER syntax. Anyway, using UNION  allows you to generate any sequence of dates, even less structured ones.

You can use a Table Valued parameter for this, then compose the rest of the query around it.
First create a table type (note the inline PK which makes this more efficient).
CREATE TYPE dbo.DateList AS TABLE (Value date PRIMARY KEY);

Then you create an IQueryable for that parameter using Raw SQL. You must do this in a separate step, you can't do it as part of the main query expression, because it won't get translated properly.
var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
    { "Value", typeof(DateOnly) },
} };
foreach (var date in YourDateList)
    table.Add(date);

var tvpQuery = dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<DateOnly>(
    "SELECT * FROM @tvp1",
    new SqlParameter("@tvp1", SqlDbType.Structured) { TypeName = "dbo.DateList", Value = table }
);

Then compose as normal:
var query =
    from WeekStart in tvpQuery
    select new {
        WeekStart,
        ActiveUsers = dbContext.Logins.Where(l =>
            l.Timestamp >= WeekStart
            && l.Timestamp < WeekStart.AddDays(7)
        ).Distinct().Count(),
        Downloads = dbContext.Downloads.Where(dl =>
            dl.Timestamp >= WeekStart
            && dl.Timestamp < WeekStart.AddDays(7)
        ).Count(),
    };

Note that using a DateOnly in a TVP is only supported from SqlClient v6 which is still in Preview. Otherwise use a DateTime.

Hehe, I remembered your answer here and figured you might post something along those lines. This solution is more appropriate when the week values don't have regular intervals.

Yes that wasn't made clear in the question. This one is also a little bit more involved because the count distinct and the DATEADD(week so I didn't dupe-close it.
